# Переключаться В или НА другой режим (функционирования)?

Tags: предлоги

> Это последнее, что помню, потому что вскоре я **переключилась в другой
>   режим** – разглядывала фрески и снова вела себя, как шестилетняя
>   девочка в Эрмитаже, которая расталкивает всех и практически залезает в
>   рот экскурсоводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, допустимы оба варианта, хотя они немного отличаются по смыслу и вряд ли всегда взаимозаменяемы. В литературе, в том числе добротной, встречается и то и другое, но **В** (для "переключения в режим") попадается намного чаще. Викисловарь для приборов и оборудования предлагает "П. в другой режим". Вывод: я бы оставил как есть.